# How did he survive?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

A man walks into a bathroom shoots himself in the head. Later he walks out unharmed. How did he survive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He survived because he

> Shot his reflection on the mirror in the head.

Answer (score 5):

I think that

> He just took a selfie with his cellphone or camera.

Comment: I think it's probably this, since the puzzle has wordplay attached to it.

Answer (score 2):

I will go wild with this one:

> He survived because he is a time traveler and just murdered his past self. Technically, that would be shooting "himself" in the head.

Comment: Make sure to hide the answer behind a spoiler tag! You can do this by inserting a `>!` before the answer portion. I've went ahead and added it for you this time :)

Answer (score 2):

Easy,

> He shot a man named "Himself" in the head, who was his target for assassination.